# Concatenation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, concatenation

```
var os = $.client.os; // mac
var browser = $.client.browser; // firefox
var browserversion = $.client.browserversion; // 3
$('#root').addClass( os + browser + browserversion );
```

.. results in `<div id="root" class="macfirefox3">`. How do I add spaces between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another variation of the same:

```
$('#root').addClass([
    $.client.os,
    $.client.browser,
    $.client.browserversion
].join(' '));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#root').addClass( os + " " + browser + " " + browserversion );
```

Comment: @Nimbuz: this is the neat way.

Comment: @Nimbuz: What would make this *neat*, in your opinion? ... OK. I thought so. :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering jQuery's philosophy, the addClass method should really accept an array or multiple strings as arguments without you having to concatenate them.

So here's my 2 cent plugin called addClasses, basically a wrapper around what Marko did.

```
jQuery.fn.addClasses = function() {
    var classes = [];
    $.each(arguments, function(index, name) {
        classes.push(name);
    });
    this.addClass(classes.join(' '));
};
```

Allows you to send any number of class names as string arguments.

```
$('div').addClasses('message', 'greeting', 'w00t');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate spaces too, Falcon gave you an example already